# Unable to specify standard language for OneNote auto correction

Tags: spell-checking, autocorrect, onenote

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this, but maybe someone knows the answer:

I'm using a german version of OneNote 2010 and can't switch the standard language for new notes to german. I always have to mark the text afterwards and set the language to german, which is very annoying. But if I start a new note the standard language is always english.

I think this is because I'm using an english keyboard layout.

So does anybody know how to tell OneNote to set the initial language for all notes to german although I'm using an english keyboard layout?

Comment: this might be because of lack support towards the German language.

Comment: No, because my colleagues have no problem. But I'm the only one using an english keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

In onenote options (file->options) go to language and set your language as default. install language proofing if needed